# Tiny MCE don't running corectly on localhost using XAMPP?

Tags: javascript, php, tinymce, tinymce-4

This is my localhost using XAMPP 5.6.12 and I am already download TinyMCE package from their website. In my local directory, I am creating a file name editor as Rich Text Editor, using TinyMCE 4.2.6.

This is editor.php [updated] source code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        tinymce.init({
            selector: "#mytextarea",
            theme: "modern",
            menubar: false,
            height: 300
        });
    </script>
    <title>JS Rich-Text Editor</title>
</head>
<body style="font-family:fantasy">

<form method="post" action="somepage">
    <p>JS Rich-Text Editor</p>
    <p><a href="" style="color:royalblue" target="_blank">Open New Tab</a></p>
    <textarea id="mytextarea">Easy! You should check out MoxieManager!</textarea>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Everything is okay if I am using CDN from tinymce.cachefly.net, but not with my fresh download package. It turn to be like a simple textarea rather than rich text editor, like I want it.

Is there anyone can help me resolve this ? And for addtional is don't auto refresh 'textarea' content, how it's can be done ?

My Firebug Console :

```
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' in theme.min.js (line 1)
TypeError: c is not a constructor ...place(/-/,""),c=T.get(n.theme),t.theme=new c(t,T.urls[n.theme]),t.theme.init&&t.... in tinymce.min.js (line 9, col 24675)
```

Comment: Are you noticing any errors in your browser console?

Comment: Also, the './' indicates that your "tinymce" directory is in the current working directory, that is the same directory as your HTML file, are you sure that is the case? Are you sure you aren't trying to do '/' instead, without the dot(.)?

Comment: @NaijaProgrammer nope. There are no error appear on my browser console and on firebug extension, installed on my browser. And 'tinymce' is in same directory with my php file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Everything is okay if I am using CDN from tinymce.cachefly.net".

Firstly, the `./` indicates that your "tinymce" directory is in the current working directory, that is the same directory as your HTML file, are you sure that is the case? Try replacing the `./` with `/` instead, without the dot(.)?

Secondly, the call to the `tinymce.init()` method comes before the declaration of your textarea with ID `mytextarea`. Try bringing your script below your HTML form or better still make the `init` call when the document has fully loaded.